# how to make sure my process that i am starting will close of my application crash

Tags: c#, winforms

in my application i m open Wireshark process and start capturing packts, in the UI i have Start button who start the capturing and Stop button who stop capturing and i am doing this by killing my wireshark process.
my question is if i am close my application in the middle of the capturing but nor with my Stop button my Wireshark process continue to run, how can i handle this situation and make sure that my process will close if my application crash or someone close it in the middle of capturing

```
public void startCapturing()
{            
    ThreadStart tStarter = delegate { openAdapterForStatistics(_device); };
    Thread thread = new Thread(tStarter);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
    ProcessStartInfo tsharkStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    tsharkStartInfo.FileName = _tshark; 
    tsharkStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
    tsharkStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; 
    tsharkStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; 
    tsharkStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
    tsharkStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
    tsharkStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" -i " + _interfaceNumber + " -s " + _packetLimitSize + " -w " + _pcapPath);
    _tsharkProcess.StartInfo = tsharkStartInfo;
    _tsharkProcess.ErrorDataReceived += _cmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
    _tsharkProcess.OutputDataReceived += tshark_OutputDataReceived; 
    _tsharkProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 
    _tsharkProcess.Start();
    _tsharkProcess.BeginOutputReadLine(); 
    _tsharkProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();                  
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(_pcapPath);
    string directoryName = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
    FileInfo[] dirs = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
    _file = dirs.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name.Equals(fileInfo.Name));
    _tsharkProcess.WaitForExit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're handling exceptions using `try-catch`, you can make sure the Wireshark process is closed in the `finally` block at the end of your topmost `try-catch` statement. From the MSDN documentation:

"The finally block is useful for cleaning up any resources allocated in the try block. Control is always passed to the finally block regardless of how the try block exits."

For example:

```
try
{
    // Your application's code.
}
catch( Exception )
{
    // Handle, log, whatever.
}
finally
{
    // Make sure Wireshark process is killed.
}
```

The code in the `finally` block will always get executed whether or not there was an exception.

Comment: my Wireshark class who open the process has start capture method and Kill method so where to put this code ?

Comment: This really depends on the structure of your code. I don't know your code's structure, so I can't say for sure. If you want to make sure Wireshark is closed no matter where an exception is thrown, you need to put this `try-catch-finally` at the highest point you have control over. For example, if it is a console app you should put it in the Main method. If it is a GUI app, your main form's OnLoad event might work.

Comment: i update my code and add my start capture method (part of Tshark class)

Answer (score 1):

You can't be 100% sure. If your application crashes in a 'civilized' manner, you can close the Wireshark process (much like @jebar8 suggested). Unfortunately, your application could crash in a way that doesn't run your `finally` code (if it's out of memory or your main thread is out of stack space, for example).

If you want to take that into account as well, you need a third process. Write up a small program that will launch your application and monitor it. If your application process disappears, your monitoring process can then kill Wirehsark is it's alive. Since the monitoring program is a short and simple one, the chance of it crashing unexpectedly are very slim.